# Using Different Sources for Testing and Release Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build, android-gradle-plugin

I am writing tests to code that make calls to a RESTful web service. I need to use different variables for testing, staging and production. For an example staging release url can be 'myapp.staging.com' whereas when I test the staging flavor it should be 'localhost/27015'. Same goes for the production flavor. When it is the release it should be 'myapp.production.com'. How do I achieve these flavor, buildType combinations?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: @Amy I learned that I can use buildConfigField to store variables. But this approach doesn't allow me to use different values for different flavor and build type variants. For an example release build type would always point to a single url (regardless the flavor being staging or live). I want the urls to be different based on buildType as well as flavor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the BuildType and the flavor to achieve it.

If you want different url for the different combination you can use a values inside your resources.

Using flavor1, flavor2 you have **4 Build Variants**.
You can set the url inside the a resource, for example in the `strings.xml` file.
Then you can set different files in these folder to achieve what you want.

```
src/flavor1/
src/flavor1Debug/
src/flavor1Release/
src/flavor2/
src/flavor2Debug/
src/flavor2Release/
```

You can set all the other values, for example the `applicationId` , in the `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it's possible using productFlavours within your gradle file, so the each build variant would have it's own

- app icon
- app name
- constants(Base API URL)

[Reference](http://tulipemoutarde.be/2013/10/06/gradle-build-variants-for-your-android-project.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what we are Doing... This is our build File of our App.

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.XXXX.XXXXfyd'
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 55
        versionName "1.0.0"

        multiDexEnabled true

        buildConfigField "boolean", "OTP_ENABLED", "false";
        buildConfigField "boolean", "MINT_API_ENABLED", "false";
        buildConfigField "String", "MINT_API_KEY", "\"XXCVVF\"";

        resValue "string", "app_name", "XXXXfyd Debug"
        resValue "string", "account_name", "XXXXfyd Debug"
        resValue "string", "account_type", "com.XXXX.XXXXfyd.debug"
        resValue "string", "account_authority", "com.mind.eventifyd.debug.provider"

        buildConfigField "String", "ACCOUNT_NAME", "\"XXXXfyd Debug\""
        buildConfigField "String", "ACCOUNT_TYPE", "\"com.XXXX.XXXXfyd.debug\""
        buildConfigField "String", "ACCOUNT_AUTHORITY", "\"com.XXXX.XXXXfyd.debug.provider\""

        buildConfigField "String", "XXXXXFYD_XXXXX_URI", "\"http://XXX.XXX.XX.XX\"";
        buildConfigField "String", "XXXXFYD_XXXX_URI", "\"XXXX//XXXXX@XXX.XXX.XX.XX:XXXXX\""
    }
 buildTypes {
        release {
          /*  zipAlignEnabled true
            minifyEnabled true*/
            shrinkResources false
            debuggable false
          /*  proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'*/
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            versionNameSuffix "-build." + getDate()

            resValue "string", "app_name", "XXXXXfyd"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "OTP_ENABLED", "false";
            buildConfigField "boolean", "MINT_API_ENABLED", "true";
            buildConfigField "String", "MINT_API_KEY", "\"efrtgyhu\"";

            resValue "string", "account_name", "XXXXXfyd"
            resValue "string", "account_type", "com.XXXX.XXXXfyd"
            resValue "string", "account_authority", "com.XXXX.XXXXfyd.provider"

            buildConfigField "String", "ACCOUNT_NAME", "\"XXXXifyd\""
            buildConfigField "String", "ACCOUNT_TYPE", "\"com.XXXX.XXXXifyd\""
            buildConfigField "String", "ACCOUNT_AUTHORITY", "\"com.XXXX.XXXXfyd.provider\""

            buildConfigField "String", "XXXFYD_XXXX_URI", "\"https://com.XXXX.XXXXfyd.XXXXXes.com\"";
            buildConfigField "String", XXXXXFYD_XXXX_URI", "\"XXXX://XXXXX@XXXXXfyd.XXXXerXXXXs.com:XXXX\""
        }
        debug {
          /*  zipAlignEnabled true
            minifyEnabled false*/
            debuggable true
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            versionNameSuffix "-debug-build." + getDate()
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        dev {
            minSdkVersion 19
        }
        prod {
            minSdkVersion 17
        }
    }
```